# Have traditionally pure math departments gotten more 'applied' with the boom in Data Science?

Tags: phd, research-process, mathematics, theory

Specifically, I am thinking of top pure math departments in the U.S., e.g., Harvard, Columbia, Princeton, Yale, UCLA, Berkeley, etc.

I know that many of these top places now have entirely separate interdisciplinary Applied Math PhD programs, and very soon Data Science PhD programs, but I'm wondering about whether the pure math groups themselves have gotten more applied.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Pure Math is Pure Math. Plain and  simple. If you want Applied Math, go to Applied Math program.

Comment: I upvoted this because it is a well-posed question that admits a clear answer.

Comment: Thanks, professor, @TomChurch; I'm happy to accept your answer if you post one! :)

Comment: @scaaahu I disagree - the division between applied and pure math has always been artificial at best, sometime ridiculous.

Comment: @Dirk I agree and have voted to close this question as being primarily opinion-based. If others disagree, I would be interested to read their answers to it.

Comment: I'm not sure why this question was closed, as it's meaning is clear.  The answer is no, research interests of faculty at top pure math departments have not become at all more applied.